# transform apply order in OpenGL confuse me

Tags: c++, glm-math

I read this tutorial, https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations
At the end, above the last picture, it says:

```
glm::mat4 trans;
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

I do not know what is the final trans values is, it is **translate * rotate** or **rotate * translate** ?

> Here we first rotate the container around the origin (0,0,0) and once
>   it's rotated, we translate its rotated version to the bottom-right
>   corner of the screen. **Remember that the actual transformation order
>   should be read in reverse: even though in code we first translate and
>   then later rotate, the actual transformations first apply a rotation
>   and then a translation.**

so the final **transform = translate * rotate** ?
but why it does not write code like this:

```
glm::mat4 trans;
trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f)); // revise order
```

the code in vertex shader is like:
`gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);`
this seems like **transform = translate * rotate** because we need first apply rotate and then translate.

update:
So, I know the multiply need read from right to left, because it is column major matrix, but I do not understand is when construct trans matrix, why do not use the revised version ?

Comment: What exactly is what you don't understand? The quote is correct, and if you want to rotate and then translate you will form a transformation matrix like `transform = translate * rotate` and then  `transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);` as in the example.

Comment: @wdc I do't understand is why it does not write code like this , ` glm::mat4 trans; trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f)); // revise order`

Comment: As @wdc pointed out, the formula for a transform is translate * rotate. However, since this is matrix multiplication, you must read it from right to left, thus the rotation will be applied before the translation.

Answer (score 1):

Output of the:

```
glm::mat4 trans;
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

Should be **translate*rotate**, I suspect that the authors wanted to mimic the left-to-right reading order not the order in which they are applied. You can confirm this by looking throught [source code](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/ext/matrix_transform.inl):

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> translate(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
    Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
    return Result;
}
```

This computes **m*translationMat**. Because the top 3x3 corner for the translation matrix is the identity and fourth column is `(v,1.0)`.