# Why OpenGL transformation order in reversed compare to what is write in code?

Tags: glm-math

In the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560301/transform-apply-order-in-opengl-confuse-me/52560674#52560674), I'm confused with the order of multiply to build a final transform matrix, but I do not describe the question clearly. So I create a new question here.

The author says:

> Here we first rotate the container around the origin (0,0,0) and once
>   it's rotated, we translate its rotated version to the bottom-right
>   corner of the screen. **Remember that the actual transformation order
>   should be read in reverse: even though in code we first translate and
>   then later rotate, the actual transformations first apply a rotation
>   and then a translation.**

So, why the actual transformation order is applied in reversed order ?

I have searched on the web, and find this is mentioned in some place, like page 16 in this  [lecture03 slide](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~emmanuel/courses/cs543/f13/slides/lecture03_p3.pdf), and page 12 on [this lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s09/www/lec/03/lec03a.pdf) , but they all not describe the reason behind it

Answer (score 2):

Generally these operations are defined by right-multiplying the given transform matrix on the modelview matrix (e.g. MV * T, where MV is the modelview matrix and T is the transform in question).

At the end of the transform chain, geometry vectors are implicitly right multiplied on the accumulated set of matrix transforms (e.g. MV * T1 * T2 * T3 * x, where T1, T2, and T3 are transformations (usually T1 = translate, T2 = rotate, T3 = scale), and x is any geometry vector).  Thus, the last transform applied actually touches the geometry vector first (e.g. T3 * x).  It's effectively grouped as (MV * (T1 * (T2 * (T3 * x)))), but of course it's equivalent to ((((MV * T1) * T2) * T3) * x) because matrix multiplication is associative.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in linear algebra, operation order is reversed.